# How do I forward-declare a constexpr object at namespace scope?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

On clang (trunk) I can forward declare an object that will later be defined with `constexpr` as follows:

```
// Fwd-declarations
struct S;
extern const S s;

// (... later) definitions
struct S {};
constexpr S s {};
```

Gcc 4.8 doesn't like this, telling me the forward-declaration and the definition differ in `constexpr`-ness. Is gcc speaking truth, or is this just a gcc bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real answer is that gcc is plain wrong, clang is right. The code above should compile, and it will in gcc 4.9. Or so says [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59123).

Answer (score 5):

I can't find any language in my copy of the C++11 standard that explicitly forbids `constexpr`-ness from mis-matching between a declaration and a definition, but I do see language explicitly forbidding `constexpr` from being used with `extern` (section 7.1.5), and I also see language requiring the initializer for a class-level `static` `constexpr` variable to be in the class.  Also, since the utility of `constexpr` is significantly reduced when the definition of the variable or its type is unavailable, I think it's likely the intent is that `constexpr` variables must be defined (or, for `static` class members, initialized) when they are declared.

As a work-around, perhaps you could provide an `extern` alias for the variable.  This would allow you to take its address, and that's the only thing I can think of that a forward-declaration would allow.  For example:

```
// .hpp file:
struct C;
extern C const &c;

// .cpp file:
struct C {
    constexpr C() { }
};
constexpr C cc;
C const &c = cc;
```

Side note:  I know that in C++14, they revisited/are revisiting `constexpr`, so it's possible that it works in Clang because it's implementing some draft spec of C++14.

Comment: C++14 draft implementation must be enabled with `-std=c++1y`; there's hardly a way to do it by accident.

Comment: @Griwes I don't use Clang currently (I'd like to, though), so I didn't know that, but it doesn't surprise me.  But Clang may have broadened their `constexpr` support across the board (in a compatible way) while working on C++14.  I'm just throwing it out as a possibility.  Since I can't find verbiage either way in the standard, it could be that both implementations are valid choices for C++11, or this could be a standard defect.

Comment: OK, sounds like a gcc bug. I've filed it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59123).

Comment: *"I think it's likely the intent is that `constexpr` variables must be defined when they are declared"* That's exactly what the Standard says, no interpretation required ;) [dcl.constexpr]/1 "The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the **definition** of a variable" (emphasis mine). I think `extern constexpr int i = 5;` is therefore allowed as well, but `extern constexpr int i;` is forbidden because *it's not a definition* (see the example in [dcl.constexpr]/1).

Comment: DyP, just because `constexpr` must be used on the definition doesn't mean that you can't forward-declare an object, it just means `constexpr` can't appear in the forward-declaration. I've seen nothing so far that tells me that my original code is invalid.

Comment: Follow-up: the bug was confirmed and is already fixed for gcc 4.9.0. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59123).

Comment: What forbids `constexpr` from being used with `extern`? I see nothing to that effect for objects or for functions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, in my draft copy of the '11 standard, section 7.1.5:1 says that `constexpr` can only be used on the **definition** of an object; `extern` can only be used to **declare** (not **define**) an object.  (`constexpr` can also be used when declaring a function, or when declaring a static data member, but `extern` isn't used for these declarations, except possibly redundantly for a function declaration or to change linkage, and the OP is about objects, so that's not really relevant.)  Note the non-normative example given: `extern constexpr int memsz; // error: not a definition`.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson 3.1/2: "A declaration is a definition unless … it contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) … and neither an initializer nor a function-body…" A `constexpr` object declaration requires an initializer and `extern` merely doesn't waive that requirement, but `extern constexpr int q = 3;` is still valid.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, well, you learn something new every day.  (Thanks for the enlightenment.)  However, the OP did want to forward declare a `constexpr` object, which one can't do using `constexpr`, so to do what the OP wants to do, it would need to be legal to mismatch `constexpr` between declaration and definition.  But I think you may be right that other uses of `constexpr` and `extern` together to define an object may be legal (but would have to be an actual **definition**).